# Show image depending on user reputation - Spring MVC - Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to show an image depending on the user reputation. I tested the image beforehand so I know the URL is correct. But i'm having some trouble with my switch case syntax:

```
<th:block th:switch="${reputation}">
  <div th:case="${reputation} &lt; 0">
       <img  th:src="@{/css/img/troll.png}"/>
  </div>
  <div th:case="0">
       <img  th:src="@{/css/img/smeagol.jpg}"/>
  </div>
  <div th:case="${reputation} &gt; 0 && ${reputation} &lt; 5">
       <img  th:src="@{/css/img/samwise.png}"/>
   </div>
   <div th:case="${reputation} &ge; 5 && ${reputation} &le; 15">
       <img  th:src="@{/css/img/frodo.png}"/>
   </div>
   <div th:case="${reputation} &gt; 15">
       <img  th:src="@{/css/img/gandalf.jpg}"/>
   </div>
</th:block>
```

which gives me the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 61; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

It's probably giving me this error because i'm trying to work with two ranges in the case?

I have scoured the internet, but I am unable to find an example of such a switch implementation.

Comment: have you tried replacing `&&` with `&amp;&amp;` ? Or with spel expression as `${reputation &gt; 5 and reputation &lt; 5}`

Comment: that gives me a new error: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [reputation > 0 and < 5] @19: EL1070E: Problem parsing left operand

Comment: `${reputation &gt; 0 and reputation &lt; 5}` . you have to specify the `reputation` twice. does not seem to be twice from the spel expression

Comment: that gives me the following error: .thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "reputation ≥ 5 and reputation ≤ 15" (userpage:37)] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (8805) '≥'
it seems it can't handle greater then or equal? I changed it to gt, and then it always shows smeagol which is odd because the reputation for this user is 2, and so samwise.png should be shown.

Comment: @sfat do you have any idea what could still be the problem? Still haven't figured it out